# chromeOptions - "ignore-certificate-errors" does not get rid of err_cert_authority_invalid error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using appium version 1.5.3 and Android Emulator 7.1.1.

I launch android driver and set chrome options as following since application under test does not have valid ssl certificate:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 0);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "XXX");                          
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "XXX");                
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

wd = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But despite setting `ignore-certificate-errors` to `true` I end up with following error on chrome browser:

[image]

- Is there any other capability I need to set?

Answer (score 6):

The flag `--ignore-certificate-errors` was added to the *bad flags* list, since it reduces the browser's security. To disable these unsupported flags you should add the `--test-type` option, as follows:

```
options.addArguments("--test-type");
```

More info [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376424).

Comment: Tried, yet same error. I wonder if this solution is for Chrome desktop browser and not Chrome mobile browser